# Windows Server 2008 - Task Scheduler and Running Scripts every minute

Tags: windows-server-2008, task-scheduler

All,

I need to schedule a task (batch script) to run once per minute, every day.
Looking at the Task Scheduler, I see the minimum repeat interval for a task is 5 minute, which is located in the "Trigger" window dropdown.

How do you do schedule tasks to run more frequently than 5 minutes using the Task Scheduler?

Thanks Much

Answer (score 1):

That dropdown box you speak of is editable. Just change the value to "1 minute"